# GraphQL types being defined as unknown in Typescript when compiled by Relay

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, relayjs, hasura

I am new to using Typescript and finding there is a mismatch in how the types are being handled from the GraphQL schema and types generated via Relay.

Here is an example:

```
# in schema.graphql
"""
columns and relationships of "businesses"
"""
type businesses implements Node {
  businessId: bigint!
  name: String!
}
```

```js
// in __generated__/Business_business.graphql
export type Business_business = {
    readonly name: string;
    readonly businessId: unknown;
    readonly " $refType": "Business_business";
};
export type Business_business$data = Business_business;
export type Business_business$key = {
    readonly " $data"?: Business_business$data;
    readonly " $fragmentRefs": FragmentRefs<"Business_business">;
};
```

```js
const BusinessFragment = graphql`
  fragment Business_business on businesses {
    name
    businessId
  }
`

type Props = {
  fragmentRef: Business_business$key
}

const Business = ({ fragmentRef }: Props) => {
  const business = useFragment(BusinessFragment, fragmentRef)
  return (
    <div>
      <p>my html!</>
      {/* I get the error: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number' for businessId */}
      <ChildComponent businessId={business.businessId} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

```js
interface Props {
  businessId: number
}

const ChildComponent = ({ businessId }: Props) => {

  return (
    <p>my business id: {businessId}</p>
  )
}
```

Is there additional config I need to do to have Relay understand the Hasura types? I have followed the example via the [relay docs](https://relay.dev/docs/guides/type-emission/#operationfragment-selection-set-data).

I have the assumption that Relay is not compiling `bigint` to `number`.

---

**Update**

I have changed the column type in Hasura from `bigint` to `Int` and this solved the problem. Is there a way to tell Relay how to match types it is unfamiliar with? In this case cast `bigint` to `number` is totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your Update:
You can add `customScalars` within your `relay.config.js`. I'm also using Hasura and this is what I've set up:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ... your other configs
  customScalars: {
    uuid: 'string',
    int8: 'string',
    bigint: 'string',
    numeric: 'number',
    varbit: 'string',
    bit: 'string',
    char: 'string',
    varchar: 'string',
    bool: 'boolean',
    int: 'number',
    int4: 'number',
    float8: 'number',
    timestamptz: 'string',
    timetz: 'string',
    jsonb: 'Record<string, unknown>',
    _text: 'string',
    date: 'string',
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you import the type from `// in __generated__/Business_business.graphql` ?
2. Is there a typo ??  what is $key appended to the typename ?

   ```
   type Props = {
     fragmentRef: Business_business$key
   }
   ```

Comment: I have updated the question to make this import more clear.